# Open textfile locked by another application: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file

Tags: c#, streamreader, ioexception

another application creates the text file pobox.lock when a user is logged in there and writes in this file the name of this user. With the Windows editor I can open this file at runtime of the other application and read the user.

But if I try to do that from my .Net code (C#) **or even with any other application** (Notepad, Notepad++, Word) or with admin rights, it **doesn't work** and I get the message that the **file is locked**.

When opening from .Net with the following code.

```
    string path = @"C:\<myfolder>\pobox.lock";
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            string lockEntrie = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

I get this message:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked
> a portion of the file

Is there any other way to read the username from the file? Why is it possible to open the file in the editor?

Best thanks
Markus

Comment: _"With the Windows editor I can open this file at runtime"_ - sorry which application?  Because you say also that not even Notepad can open it.

Comment: Maybe change `FileShare.ReadWrite` to `FileShare.Read`?

Comment: The code you have written/copied can avoid an ERROR_SHARE_VIOLATION.  But that's not what the exception tells you, it failed on an ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION.  In other words, the other app used the equivalent of FileStream.Lock().  That's a hard lock, can't be bypassed with magic.  If the exception is consistent then you are doing something else that makes the timing of the call awkward, like starting that app yourself.  Nothing you can do but wait for a while and try again.  Do talk to the author of that other app.

Comment: @Deleted: Excuse me, windows editor = notepad.exe. I meant wordpad. With notepad I can open the file, but not with wordpad. With FileShare.Read I get a different exception, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Yes, it can be. The problem is that the other application creates the file immediately upon login and deletes it only upon exit. I can contact the developers of this application, see if they are willing to change this. The only thing that amazes me is that I can open the file with notepad.exe. Does it have any special rights?